# Can this exponent based equation be solved?

Tags: exponential-function

I have the following equation:

$y=\frac{kv}{m\left(a-b\right)}\cdot\left(\frac{e^{-at}}{a^{2}}-\frac{e^{-bt}}{b^{2}}\right)$

$k$, $v$, $m$, $a$, and $b$ are all constants. t is time in seconds.

I would like to solve $t$ for a given $y$ value. ie.  I would like to express the equation as:

$t =  ...$

I tried Wolfram Alpha and Symbolab's equation solvers but they couldn't provide an answer. Is this a difficult one or practically impossible to solve?

Comment: In a general manner, it is impossible. If $a$ and $b$ are in a ratio of $2,3,4$, it could reduce to a polynomial.

Comment: Okay thanks. I'll just iterate through it with increasing time values until I get the y value I want and then record the time value that roughly provided it.